# add new attributes into existing shortcodes

Tags: shortcode

I want to add some new attributes into existing shortocode using some functions. What about below code,

```
function btn_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'class' => 'button',
    'href'  =>  '#'
), $atts );

return '<a class="' . esc_attr($a['class']) . '" href="' . esc_attr($a['href']) . '">' . $content . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'button', 'btn_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is modify the `$a`-variable, for example, to add a `target` to this link, you would add it to the array making up the `$a`-var, and printing it later.

```
add_shortcode( 'button', 'btn_shortcode' );
function btn_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    $a = shortcode_atts(array(
        'class' => 'button',
        'href'  =>  '#',
        'target' => '_blank'
    ), $atts);

    return '<a target="' . esc_attr($a['target']) . '" class="' . esc_attr($a['class']) . '" href="' . esc_attr($a['href']) . '">' . $content . '</a>';
}
```